# how write video in grayscale using torchvision?

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

I would to save video in grayscale using torchvision method

it is working for coloring vedion but with grayscale there is problem in ndim as shown below

```
`The detector is mediapipe
INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
/Users/shaimaa/Downloads/LIP_Reading/Code/audio-visual-dataset-master/results_news/news/LRWAR_new/Politics_news_18_p2_170.mp4
this is data_filename : Politics_news_18_p2_170.mp4
this is dst_filename : /Users/shaimaa/Downloads/LIP_Reading/Code/audio-visual-dataset-master/results_news/news/LRWAR_Mouth/Politics_news_18_p2_170.mp4
/Users/shaimaa/Downloads/LIP_Reading/Code/audio-visual-dataset-master/results_news/news/LRWAR_new/Politics_news_18_p2_170.mp4
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
[array([[ 75,  72],
       [151,  71],
       [ 99, 112],
       [105, 153]]), array([[ 74,  73],
       [151,  70],
       [ 99, 112],
       [106, 153]]), array([[ 76,  71],
       [154,  70],
       [103, 114],
       [109, 154]]), array([[ 77,  70],
       [155,  69],
       [103, 112],
       [109, 152]]), array([[ 76,  70],
       [154,  68],
       [102, 112],
       [108, 152]]), array([[ 76,  68],
       [152,  67],
       [100, 108],
       [106, 148]]), array([[ 75,  69],
       [149,  68],
       [ 99, 107],
       [105, 147]]), array([[ 74,  70],
       [149,  71],
       [ 97, 109],
       [102, 149]]), array([[ 75,  72],
       [151,  71],
       [ 98, 110],
       [104, 152]]), array([[ 72,  73],
       [148,  72],
       [ 96, 111],
       [102, 152]])]
The landmarks was saved to /Users/shaimaa/Downloads/LIP_Reading/Code/audio-visual-dataset-master/results_news/news/LRWAR_Mouth/Politics_news_18_p2_170.mp4
torch.Size([10, 96, 96])
Error executing job with overrides: ['data_dir=/Users/shaimaa/Downloads/LIP_Reading/Code/audio-visual-dataset-master/results_news/news/LRWAR_new', 'dst_dir=/Users/shaimaa/Downloads/LIP_Reading/Code/audio-visual-dataset-master/results_news/news/LRWAR_Mouth']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "crop_mouth.py", line 63, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/shaimaa/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hydra/main.py", line 94, in decorated_main
    _run_hydra(
  File "/Users/shaimaa/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hydra/_internal/utils.py", line 394, in _run_hydra
    _run_app(
  File "/Users/shaimaa/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hydra/_internal/utils.py", line 457, in _run_app
    run_and_report(
  File "/Users/shaimaa/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hydra/_internal/utils.py", line 223, in run_and_report
    raise ex
  File "/Users/shaimaa/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hydra/_internal/utils.py", line 220, in run_and_report
    return func()
  File "/Users/shaimaa/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hydra/_internal/utils.py", line 458, in <lambda>
    lambda: hydra.run(
  File "/Users/shaimaa/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hydra/_internal/hydra.py", line 132, in run
    _ = ret.return_value
  File "/Users/shaimaa/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hydra/core/utils.py", line 260, in return_value
    raise self._return_value
  File "/Users/shaimaa/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hydra/core/utils.py", line 186, in run_job
    ret.return_value = task_function(task_cfg)
  File "crop_mouth.py", line 58, in main
    save2vid(dst_filename, data, fps)
  File "crop_mouth.py", line 21, in save2vid
    torchvision.io.write_video(filename, vid, frames_per_second)
  File "/Users/shaimaa/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchvision/io/video.py", line 132, in write_video
    frame = av.VideoFrame.from_ndarray(img, format="rgb24")
  File "av/video/frame.pyx", line 408, in av.video.frame.VideoFrame.from_ndarray
  File "av/utils.pyx", line 72, in av.utils.check_ndarray
ValueError: Expected numpy array with ndim `3` but got `2``
```

this is link of code in GitHub [https://github.com/mpc001/Visual_Speech_Recognition_for_Multiple_Languages/tree/master](https://stackoverflow.com)

I tried it with coloring videos it is fine work

Answer (score 0):

the model is probably expecting something in the format (Batch, Channels, Width, Height), being Channels = 3. Seems that your transformation is making it to have Channels = 1.

1. It is not the same thing, but one thing you can do is simple copy and paste the information from the other two channels so that you image will looks like grayscale:

> ```
> image[:,:,0] = image[:,:,1] 
>
> image[:,:,2] = image[:,:,1]
> ```

2. Maybe you are missing the batch dimension (as you print says the shape is (10,95,95) on your image. You may fix it by:

   torch.unsqueeze(image,0)
   so that the final shape should be something like:

> ```
> (10,1,95,95) instead of (10,95,95)
> ```

3. The other possibility is to change the model, which is much more difficult.